# $\biggl( \prod_{i \in \mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}/p^i\mathbb{Z}\biggr)\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q}\ne 0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

I've found this claim $$\biggl( \prod_{i \in \mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}/p^i\mathbb{Z}\biggr)\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q} \not\cong \prod_{i \in \mathbb{N}}\biggl( \mathbb{Z}/p^i\mathbb{Z}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q}\biggr)$$

Why is this true ? Any reference ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way of viewing it.

First $\mathbb{Q}\otimes \mathbb{Z}/p^i\mathbb{Z}=0$ for all $i$, so the right hand side is zero.

There is an injection

$$0\to\mathbb{Z}_p\to\prod_i \mathbb{Z}/p^i\mathbb{Z}$$

where $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the $p$-adic integers. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is flat we obtain an injection

$$0\to\mathbb{Z}_p\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Q}\to\prod_i(\mathbb{Z}/p^i\mathbb{Z})\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Q}$$

So, it suffices to show that $\mathbb{Z}_p\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Q}$ is non-zero. But, the multiplication map produces a non-zero pairing $\mathbb{Z}_p\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: Isn't $\mathbb Z_n\otimes_{\mathbb Z}\mathbb Q=0$ for all $n$, since $a\otimes b = na\otimes\frac{b}{n} = 0$?

Comment: @Christoph Yes, if by $\mathbb{Z}_n$ you mean $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. This is one of those cases, since I'm using both notions, where it is important to distinguish between the integers modulo $p$, denoted $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, and the $p$-adic integers, which I denote $\mathbb{Z}_p$ :)

Comment: Oh I see, sorry for the confusion then!

Comment: @Christoph No problem :)

Comment: Nice answer: +1

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Thanks for your kind words!

Comment: @AlexYoucis: what do you mean by pairing ?

Comment: @WLOG I just mean it gives a pairing $\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}_p$, given by $(x,y)\mapsto xy$ (where this is multiplication in $\mathbb{Q}_p$). This is $\mathbb{Z}$-bilinear, and so induces a non-zero map $\mathbb{Z}_p\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}_p$. But, there can't be a non-zero map from the zero module.

Comment: Even easier: there is an injection $\mathbb{Z}\to\prod_{i\ge0}\mathbb{Z}/p^i\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @egreg Too easy :) You're right, of course. This was just what popped out as being the most natural thing.

Comment: @egreg: great commrnt!